# Is there a way to retrieve the currently selected conda environment and/or execute commands in it?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Related to [this vscode extension issue](https://github.com/lorenzo2897/vscode-ipe/issues/162), but more of a general question.
When I select a virtual environment to use (be it virtualenv, conda, etc) is there a possibility for other extensions to retrieve the environment and to run commands into it?

Specifically for the problem in the issue linked above (as an example of the intended use case), they need to retrieve information from Jupyter, which is done via `execSync` calls. These spawn a new shell, so before running any command it's necessary to reactivate whatever environment is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Other extensions can find out what Python interpreter is selected, but other environment details are not exposed.

Comment: Is there then a way to run commands in the same context as the python interpreter? How does vscode know, for example, which pip is the one to run when installing new packages?

Comment: We use `python -m pip` so it can only be the one that is installed with the selected interpreter.